# Neovim - Getting `Cursor position outside buffer` when trying to go to definition on an external library in C# .NET

Tags: c#, neovim, omnisharp, telescope.nvim

#### Operating system/version

Linux Ubuntu 22

#### Terminal/GUI

GNOME Terminal

#### AstroNvim Health

```lua
astronvim: require("astronvim.health").check()

AstroNvim ~
- AstroNvim Version: unknown
- Neovim Version: v0.9.5
- OK Using stable Neovim >= 0.8.0
- OK `git` is installed: Used for core functionality such as updater and plugin management
- OK `xdg-open` is installed: Used for `gx` mapping for opening files with system opener (Optional)
- OK `lazygit` is installed: Used for mappings to pull up git TUI (Optional)
- OK `node` is installed: Used for mappings to pull up node REPL (Optional)
- WARNING `gdu` is not installed: Used for mappings to pull up disk usage analyzer (Optional)
- WARNING `btm` is not installed: Used for mappings to pull up system monitor (Optional)
- OK `python3` is installed: Used for mappings to pull up python REPL (Optional)
```

#### What is the goal

To try to go to definition on an external library code in C# dotnet project.
The go to definition in `omnisharp's` Mason LSP works but only for my local code, not library code. This is not ideal for working in production environment for my job.

To do this, I found the following "[omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim](https://github.com/Hoffs/omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim)" plugin which enhances Neovim's ability to navigate to the definitions of C# code, even those defined in external libraries, by decompiling and displaying their source code in a temporary buffer.

#### Changes I've made to my Astronvim config:

In `~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/` folder, I've added the following file:

```lua
-- file name "omni-extended.lua"

return { "Hoffs/omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim" }
```

In `~/.config/nvim/init.lua`, I've added the following code to setup custom [omnisharp-roslyn](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn) LSP server:

```lua
local on_attach = require("astronvim.utils.lsp").on_attach
local capabilities = require("astronvim.utils.lsp").capabilities

local pid = vim.fn.getpid()
local omnisharp_dll_path = "/home/rampage/Downloads/omnisharp-roslyn-net6/OmniSharp.dll"

local config = {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  handlers = {
    ["textDocument/definition"] = require("omnisharp_extended").handler,
  },
  cmd = { "dotnet", omnisharp_dll_path, "--languageserver", "--hostPID", tostring(pid) },

  -- Enables support for reading code style, naming convention and analyzer
  -- settings from .editorconfig.
  enable_editorconfig_support = true,

  -- If true, MSBuild project system will only load projects for files that
  -- were opened in the editor. This setting is useful for big C# codebases
  -- and allows for faster initialization of code navigation features only
  -- for projects that are relevant to code that is being edited. With this
  -- setting enabled OmniSharp may load fewer projects and may thus display
  -- incomplete reference lists for symbols.
  enable_ms_build_load_projects_on_demand = false,

  -- Enables support for roslyn analyzers, code fixes and rulesets.
  enable_roslyn_analyzers = false,

  -- Specifies whether 'using' directives should be grouped and sorted during
  -- document formatting.
  organize_imports_on_format = true,

  -- Enables support for showing unimported types and unimported extension
  -- methods in completion lists. When committed, the appropriate using
  -- directive will be added at the top of the current file. This option can
  -- have a negative impact on initial completion responsiveness,
  -- particularly for the first few completion sessions after opening a
  -- solution.
  enable_import_completion = true,

  -- Specifies whether to include preview versions of the .NET SDK when
  -- determining which version to use for project loading.
  sdk_include_prereleases = true,

  -- Only run analyzers against open files when 'enableRoslynAnalyzers' is
  -- true
  analyze_open_documents_only = false,
}

require("lspconfig").omnisharp.setup(config)
```

The above custom LSP config works **Except For Go To Definition** for external library code.

When I press `gd` for a external C# library code, I get the following error:
`Error executing vim.schedule lua callback: /usr/local/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/util.lua:1157: Cursor position outside buffer stack traceback: [C]: in function 'nvim_win_set_cursor' /usr/local/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/util.lua:1157: in function 'jump_to_location' ...nvim/lazy/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/__lsp.lua:176: in function 'handler' /usr/local/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp.lua:1393: in function '' vim/_editor.lua: in function <vim/_editor.lua:0> Press ENTER or type command to continue`

#### Additional Information

I came across the following issues which may provide more information but given that I'm new to neovim, I'm not sure if these may help:

1. https://github.com/Hoffs/omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim/issues/27
2. https://github.com/Hoffs/omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim/issues/14

For the above 2 issues, from my understanding I gathered this `Cursor position outside buffer` possibily may be a telescope issue after using the  [omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim](https://github.com/Hoffs/omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim) plugin.

Not sure if this is the correct way but I changed `~/.config/nvim/lua/astronvim/utils/lsp.lua` code from:

```lua
  if client.supports_method "textDocument/declaration" then
    lsp_mappings.n["gD"] = {
      function() vim.lsp.buf.declaration() end,
      desc = "Declaration of current symbol",
    }
  end
```

To this:

```lua
  if client.supports_method "textDocument/declaration" then
    lsp_mappings.n["gD"] = {
      "<cmd> lua require('omnisharp_extended').telescope_lsp_definitions()<CR>",
      desc = "Declaration of current symbol",
    }
  end
```

But that did not work. Same `Cursor position outside buffer` issue persisted.

My Astronvim config:
https://github.com/rampaged/nvim2

#### Steps to Reproduce

#### Prerequisite

> Install .NET 6 SDK and Runtime

1. Clone a fresh copy of Astronvim config
2. Install the [omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim](https://github.com/Hoffs/omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim) plugin
3. Follow the omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim plugin readme

   1. "[Omnisharp settings](https://github.com/Hoffs/omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim?tab=readme-ov-file#omnisharp-settings)"
   2. "[Neovim settings](https://github.com/Hoffs/omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim?tab=readme-ov-file#for-neovim-nightly-06-or-later)"
4. Create or clone a simple dotnet project that contains external library code. I've created this small C# project for testing.

   1. `git clone https://github.com/rampaged/echo-bot.git`
   2. `cd echo-bot`
   3. run `dotnet build` on the "echo-bot" root directory
5. cd to `~/.../echo-bot/Bots/EchoBot.cs` file
6. on line 12, `gd` on `ActivityHandler` code which is a external library code:
   [image]

7. Notice the error:

[image: Screenshot from 2024-02-10 14-55-16]

`Error executing vim.schedule lua callback: /usr/local/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/util.lua:1157: Cursor position outside buffer stack traceback: [C]: in function 'nvim_win_set_cursor' /usr/local/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/util.lua:1157: in function 'jump_to_location' ...nvim/lazy/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/__lsp.lua:176: in function 'handler' /usr/local/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp.lua:1393: in function '' vim/_editor.lua: in function <vim/_editor.lua:0> Press ENTER or type command to continue`

#### Expected behavior

The expected behavior is that when pressing `gd` on any external library code using the [omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim](https://github.com/Hoffs/omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim) plugin, Neovim should seamlessly navigate to the definition of the code, displaying the decompiled source or relevant definition in a new buffer, without encountering any errors or issues with cursor positioning.

I've also opened this issue in `AstroNvim` github but it got closed without an answer.
https://github.com/AstroNvim/AstroNvim/issues/2463

Please let me know if you have any questions.
Happy to provide more information as needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Any further information I can provide? I'm still interested in getting help on this. Thanks.